# Revit API Current Selection in Document Changerd Event

Tags: events, selection, revit

Is it possible to get the `UIDocument` in a `DocumentChanged` event registered from an `IExternalApplication`?  If so, how?  More specifically, i'm trying to retrieve the current selection at the time the event is fired.

I can retrieve the Transaction and effected elements, however, I cant seem to grab the "Selected" element at the time the event was fired.

```
public void app_Changed(object sender, DocumentChangedEventArgs args) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the document from within the event handler, from the [event handler arguments `GetDocument` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/7564b620-be0b-971c-1dd9-2c2061e02fec.htm).

An example is given by [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) in the comparison of the [DocumentChanged versus Dynamic Model Updater](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/06/documentchanged-versus-dynamic-model-updater.html).